# I'm trying to sum up the numbers in a given array, using recursion , tried this code but it isn't working. Why?

Tags: c++, recursion, implementation

```
#include <iostream>

   using namespace std;

   int sumByRecursion( int arr[]) {
        int sum = 0;
        int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
        //n is the size of the array
        if (n == 0) {
            return sum;
        } else {
            n -= 1;
            for (int i=0;i=n;++i){
                arr[i]=arr[i+1];
            }
            return (sum + arr[0] + sumByRecursion( arr));
        }
    }

   int main() {
        int arr[]={2, 4, 6};
        sumByRecursion( arr);

        return 0;
    }
```

sumByRecursion working based on this idea:
1-if the size of the array is 0 "empty array", return the sum.
2-if size isn't 0 "array isn't empty",  sum up the first element on sum, then call the function, reduce the array's size by 1, sumByRecursion on the new array.

Comment: `int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);` does not work the way you want it to.  Inside the function the parameter `arr` has decayed to type `int*` and knows nothing about the number of elements in the array.

Comment: It appears you are using `int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);` to determine the size of the array.  That does not calculate the size of an array.  Probably a bug.

Comment: `int arr[]={2, 4, 6};` --> `std::array<int, 3> arr = {2,4,6};`  then use `arr.size()` and not what you're using now to determine the number of elements (which as noted, is wrong).

Comment: Are you required to use recursion for code that should be a simple loop? If so, you have my sympathy. In any event, instead of removing the first element, just point at the next element. Remove that `for` loop, and for the recursive call, use `sumByRecursion(arr + 1)`. And, as other comments have noted, you should pass the size of the array as an argument.

Comment: In addition, note that you are not using the result provided by the function.

Comment: In short: `int sumByRecursion( int arr[])` is exactly the same as `int sumByRecursion( int *arr)`.  That `[]` syntax in the parameter list is nothing more than syntax sugar.  Given that, it should be more obvious as to why your function is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A (sadly) common mistake:

```cpp
int sumByRecursion( int arr[] )
{ // What do you think  ^^^^^  this is?

    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    //      ^^^^^^^^^^^ Sorry, too late.
    // ...
}
```

As already noted in the comment section

> Inside the function the parameter `arr` has decayed to type int* and knows nothing about the number of elements in the array. ([Richard Critten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70366907/im-trying-to-sum-up-the-numbers-in-a-given-array-using-recursion-tried-this#comment124387603_70366907))

> In short: `int sumByRecursion( int arr[])` is exactly the same as `int sumByRecursion( int *arr)`. That `[]` syntax in the parameter list is nothing more than syntax sugar. ([PaulMcKenzie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70366907/im-trying-to-sum-up-the-numbers-in-a-given-array-using-recursion-tried-this#comment124387783_70366907))

The solution is to pass the size alongside the pointer, either explicitly as a separate function argument or inside an object like [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) or [`std::ranges::range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range).

An alternative, of course, is to pass the couple of iterators returned by [std::cbegin()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [std::cend()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end).

---

The code used to *"reduce the array's size by 1"* is probably a result of the same misunderstanding:

```cpp
int sum = 0;
// ...
if (n == 0) {              // Ok...
    return sum;
} else {
    n -= 1;                // Okayish...
   
    for (int i=0;i=n;++i){ // 
        arr[i]=arr[i+1];   // <-- There's NO need to do all those copies!
    }                      // 

    return (sum + arr[0] + sumByRecursion( arr));
    //                                    ^^^^ This does NOT pass an array
}
```

---

[Eljay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4641116/eljay)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70367043/4944425) shows how to correctly implement OP's algorithm.

Just for fun<sup>(1)</sup>, a stack-friendlier implementation

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int sumByRecursion(size_t n, int const* arr)
{
    // Stop the bloody recursion
    if ( n == 0 )
        return 0;
    if ( n == 1 )
        return arr[0];
    
    // Divide et impera
    size_t middle = n / 2;
    return sumByRecursion(middle, arr)
         + sumByRecursion(n - middle, arr + middle);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] {2, 4, 6};

    std::cout << sumByRecursion(std::size(arr), arr) << '\n';
}
```

<sup>(1) Seriously, do NOT use this. It's utterly inefficient and uselessly convoluted. Use the right [algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) instead.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in the size of the array to the `sumByRecursion` routine.

The reason you need to pass the size of the array is because the array does not track its own size.

Alternatives like `std::array` and `std::vector` provide the capability of querying them for their size, but C-style arrays do not carry along that information.

The `std::size` function queries the *type* (which is a C-style array in that context) to figure out the size.  Once passed as an `int arr[]` parameter, that `arr` type is `int*` which no longer can produce the size information.

The `int arr[]` parameter is a way of writing `int* arr`, but suggests to the reader that the `arr` parameter is a C-style array.  Could be considered self-documenting code, when done correctly -- but many programs would express the parameter as `int* arr` so, alas, it is not a widespread idiom.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::size;
using std::size_t;

namespace {

int sumByRecursion(int arr[], size_t n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        // Many C++ compilers do not perform tail recursion optimization.
        // But for those that do, this will thwart tail recursion optimization.
        return arr[0] + sumByRecursion(arr+1, n-1);
    }
}

} // anon

int main() {
    int arr[] = {2, 4, 6};
    auto arr_size = size(arr);
    auto sum = sumByRecursion(arr, arr_size);
    cout << sum << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Really I think you should mention whey you need to pass the size.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer the solution of your problem, using the algorithm **Depth first search**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
const int maximumSize=10;
vector<int> visited(maximumSize, 0);
int dfs(int current, int previous, vector<int>& input)
{
    if(visited[current]==1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    visited[current]=1;
    int summarize=0;
    for(int next=(current+1); next<input.size(); ++next)
    {
        if(next==previous)
        {
            continue;
        }
        summarize+=dfs(next, current, input);
    }
    summarize+=input[current];
    return summarize;
}
void solve()
{
    vector<int> inputVector={2, 4, 6};
    cout<<dfs(0, -1, inputVector);
    return;
}
int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
12
```